# Why does open()ing a Linux tty hang after killing a process which configured it?

Tags: linux, tty, termios

I want to set a serial port in Linux to "raw" mode at 115200 baud. If I run the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int fd= open( "/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR );


  if ( fd < 0 )
    {
      perror(0);
      int err = errno;
      fprintf( stderr, "can't open /dev/ttyS0 got err %d\n",err );
      return err;
    }
  printf("got fd %d\n", fd );


  struct termios old;

  tcgetattr(fd,&old);

  struct termios news;
  // enable raw comms
  cfmakeraw( &news);

  // set port to 115200 baud
  cfsetispeed(&news, B115200);
  tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW,&news);

  printf("set raw 115200\n");

  usleep(5000000);

  printf( "slept\n");

  tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW,&old);

  printf( "restored\n");

  close(fd);

  printf("closed\n");
}
```

and interrupt it during the sleep with Ctrl-C, then run it again, there is no output the second time - the program hangs during the open() call. Even running as root doesn't help.

There is no indication the first process is still using the port or that the port is locked, nothing is apparent in /var/lock/ or ps aux | grep tty

My best option right now is to ensure that whenever a process using a tty is terminated it correctly closes the port. But why should this problem arise at all? Shouldn't the aborted process release the port?

Comment: Try `lsof | grep ttyS0` to find out if it's still opened somehow.

Comment: Tried that, nothing is using it apparently.

Comment: It appears to be fixed by setting the HUPCL flag: `news.c_cflag |= HUPCL;` but I can't always reproduce the problem on my i686 Debian box but is reliably reproduceable on an ARM board also running Debian.

Comment: @AlexGP Setting HUPCL didn't fix the issue for me on Ubuntu. Using atexit(...) to return old settings and close the port fixed it, but other apps don't have the same hanging issue. Wish someone would explain what magic those apps are doing to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

On my system, I found out that it was caused by a module called 'option'. After doing 'modprobe -r option', I could open the serial port without any problem.